# unicode normalizing the file input string

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I get a list of files from the file input on a page using javascript and then extract the filename for each file. I need to unicode normalize the filenames client side using javascript. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no normalization function in JavaScript itself. There is generally very little Unicode support in JavaScript except for the character concept itself and case conversions (which are Unicode-aware).

So you would need to use a library. A simple one is http://git.io/unorm which is primarily for server-side JavaScript with Node.js but can be used client-side, too. For example, using it, you would normalize the value of `s` to Normalization form C using `UNorm.normalize('NFC',s)`.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to avoid installing Node.js, but looks like its my best option

Comment: The http://git.io/unorm library does not require Node.js. I tested it as a standalone package. You only need jQuery, unorm.js, and unormdata.js.

Answer (score 0):

These days, browsers have a [`normalize()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) on strings. It's not supported by IE however.